# Error in Listing File from Directory in C++

Tags: c++, directory

I am having a problem with my code. Whenever i run the program, the last file search would return a zero value where in it shouldn't.

here is the code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream> 
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

string GetPath(string path){
        char directory[1024];
        vector <string> filelist;
        strcpy_s(directory,path.c_str());
        BOOL checker;

            WIN32_FIND_DATA findFileData;
            HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile((LPCSTR)directory, &findFileData);
            cout <<"Files in:" <<"\n"<<directory<<"\n"<<endl;
            checker = FindNextFile(hFind, &findFileData);

            while(checker)
            {
                checker = FindNextFile(hFind, &findFileData);
                filelist.push_back(findFileData.cFileName);//save file list in vector
                cout << findFileData.cFileName << endl;
            }

            DWORD error = GetLastError();
            if( error != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
            {

            }
            /*for (unsigned i=1;i<filelist.size();i++){
                cout << filelist[i]<<endl;//print out the vector
            }*/


            return 0;
}

int main()
{
   string path;
   path="C:\\Program Files\\*.*";
   vector <string> handler;
   path = GetPath(path);
}
```

Comment: If I'm reading your code right, you'll be skipping every other file as you call `FindNextFile` twice per loop. Is this intentional?

Comment: Then wouldn't your last search return 0 prematurely based on whether there are an odd or even number of files in the directory?

Comment: sorry i misread your comment. it wasn't intentional so i edited it up.. there is the new code

Comment: What error are you getting? Still the same as before? What errorcode is `GetLastError` returning?

Comment: yeah they are still the same..

Comment: It's difficult to give any real feedback to this code -- it obviously won't compile as-is, given that `GetPath` is defined to return `std::string` but attempts to return 0 instead, and it's not apparent at a glance that your post-edit `while(...)` logic has any problems. Please post a valid, compilable code sample that reproduces your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as a sanity check:

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

#ifdef UNICODE
typedef std::wstring tstring;
static std::wostream& tcout = std::wcout;
#else
typedef std::string tstring;
static std::ostream& tcout = std::cout;
#endif

std::vector<tstring> GetPath(tstring const& path)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA findFileData;
    HANDLE const hFind = FindFirstFile(path.c_str(), &findFileData);
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        throw std::runtime_error(""); // realistically, throw something useful

    std::vector<tstring> filelist;
    do filelist.push_back(findFileData.cFileName);
    while (FindNextFile(hFind, &findFileData));
    FindClose(hFind);
    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
        throw std::runtime_error(""); // realistically, throw something useful
    return filelist;
}

int _tmain()
{
    std::vector<tstring> files = GetPath(_T("C:\\Program Files\\*.*"));
    for (std::vector<tstring>::const_iterator iter = files.begin(), iter_end = files.end(); iter != iter_end; ++iter)
        tcout << *iter << _T('\n');
}
```

If it works, clean up the error handling logic and use it ;-]. If it doesn't, then @young was correct and you you have localization issues; change your project settings to use Unicode as the character set and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to check `hFind` returned from FindFirstFile() as it may return `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.

Second, your while loop should look like this

```
while(FindNextFile(hFind, &findFileData)!= 0)
{
    filelist.push_back(findFileData.cFileName);//save file list in vector
}

DWORD error = GetLastError();
if( error != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
{
    // You are not expecting this error so you might want to do something here.
}
```

Comment: @Andro, Does any of your files have non-english characters? It would be great if you upload the real path and the names of files in it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you shouldn't be calling  FindNextFile inside the loop: I imagine that if you look at you output carefully you will notice that every SECOND file is missing from your list.

This is because the call to FindNextFile  in the while condition loads the next file detail into FindFileData. Then the next line of code (inside the while loop) does this process again overwriting the first match with the second. Thus you only get every second entry.

For even numbers of files you also get the difficulty you describe at the end.

Comment: if i will put the FindNextFile outside the loop it wont work?

Comment: I assume he means inside the loop body (i.e., the loop's braces), not inside the loop expression.

Answer (score 1):

Well one thing I notice is that your GetPath function returns a string. At the end you do: return 0; This will call the string constructor that takes a char* as parameter and will attempt to construct the string with a null pointer. I assume this will lead to a crash in most STl implementations :-).

Coming to your problem, you could try this:

```
#include <Strsafe.h>

//from MSDN
void 
DisplayError(LPTSTR lpszFunction) 
{ 
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

    FormatMessage( FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
                   FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
                   FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                   NULL,
                   dw,
                   MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
                   (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
                   0, 
                   NULL );

    // Display the error message and exit the process

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR)); 

    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, 
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"), 
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf); 

    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
}

void 
GetPath(string path)
{
    vector <string> filelist;

    WIN32_FIND_DATA findFileData;
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(path.c_str(), &findFileData);

    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    {
        DisplayError("FindFirstFile");
        return;
    } 

    cout <<"Enumerating files in: " <<"\n"<< path << "\n" << endl;

    while( FindNextFile(hFind, &findFileData) != 0 )
    {
        filelist.push_back( findFileData.cFileName );//save file list in vector
    }

    if (  ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES != GetLastError() )
    {
        DisplayError("FindFirstFile");
    }

    FindClose(hFind);

    unsigned int listSize = filelist.size();

    cout << "List Count: " << listSize << "\n";

    for (unsigned i=0; i  < listSize; ++i)
    {
        cout << filelist[i] << "\n";//print out the vector
    }

    cout << "\nListing complete\n" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    string path;
    path="C:\\Program Files\\*.*";
    GetPath(path);
}
```

And tell us what error code do you receive after the while loop completes.

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream> 
#include <conio.h>
#include <sys\types.h>
#include <sys\stat.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <exception>
#include <WinBase.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <algorithm>

        using namespace std;
int ifException(string directory) throw()
    {
        DWORD returnvalue;
        returnvalue = GetFileAttributes(directory.c_str());
            if(returnvalue == ((DWORD)-1))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {   
                return 1;
            }
}
string FileTime(string filename, string path){

    char timeStr[ 100 ] = "";
    char fpath[9999];
    string buffer;

                replace (path.begin(),path.end(),'*','\0');
                replace (path.begin(),path.end(),'.','\0');
                strcpy_s(fpath,path.c_str());
                path = filename;
            struct stat buf;
            string filepath;
            filepath = fpath;
            filepath += filename;
            //cout << filepath << endl;
            strcpy_s(fpath,filepath.c_str());
            if (!stat(fpath, &buf))
            {
                strftime(timeStr, 100, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", localtime(&buf.st_mtime));
            }
            buffer = filename;
            buffer += "\t\t";
            buffer +=timeStr;
            return buffer;
}


vector <string> GetPath(string path)
    {
            char directory[9999];
            vector <string> filelist;
            string buffer;
            strcpy_s(directory,path.c_str());
            BOOL checker;
                WIN32_FIND_DATA findFileData;
                HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile((LPCSTR)directory, &findFileData);


                try
                    {
                        ifException(directory);

                    }catch(int i)
                    {   
                        if (i==0)
                        {
                            _getch();
                            exit(1);
                        }
                    }
                buffer = findFileData.cFileName;
                filelist.push_back(buffer);
                checker = FindNextFile(hFind, &findFileData);
                while(checker)
                {
                    checker = FindNextFile(hFind, &findFileData);
                        buffer = findFileData.cFileName;
                        buffer = FileTime(buffer,path);
                    filelist.push_back(buffer);//save file list in vector
                    if(checker == 0)
                    {
                        filelist.resize(filelist.size());
                        return filelist;
                    }
                }
    return filelist;
    }

    int main()
    {
       string path;

       path="C:\\Documents and Settings\\OJT\\My Documents\\*.*";// the directory
       vector <string> handler;
       handler = GetPath(path);
        for (unsigned i=1;i<handler.size()-1;i++)
        {
            cout << handler[i]<<endl;//print out the vector
        }
       _getch();
    }
```

Comment: This code still isn't correct, as it skips the first file inside a given directory.

Comment: there you go i added it up.. tnx for the help ildjarn

Comment: Still not correct -- now it skips the second file inside a given directory.